# Merge data from tables while selecting based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the feeling that this should be achievable quite easily, but am somehow struggeling a little bit.
I want to join two tables while at the same time restrict myself on two categories of the second table.

Main data tabe:

| ID | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bla |
| 2 | blubb |

The other table holds the additional info:

| ID | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 5 |
| 1 | orange | 3 |
| 1 | pear | 0 |
| 2 | apple | 4 |

As a result I would expect something like this:

| ID | data | apple | orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bla | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | blubb | 4 | null |

Could you give my a hint? Is that a pivot?

Comment: Tag your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be pivot but not necessarily. You didn't tag your database, so below solution is general that would work with most SQL series databases and doesn't need some capabilities\extensions:

```
select mainTable.Id, mainTable.data, 
   sum(case when otherTable.key = 'apple' then otherTable.Value end) as Apple,
   sum(case when otherTable.key = 'orange' then otherTable.Value end) as Orange
from mainTable 
left join otherTable on mainTable.id = otherTable.Id
group by mainTable.Id, mainTable.data;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UG32vHXV)

Comment: Yep. It's even more succinct with decode: `SUM(DECODE(key,'apple',value)) apple`

Comment: @PaulW, I didn't know the database when I sent it.

Comment: @PaulW Probably just personal preference, but I've always found DECODES far less readable than CASE WHEN. Especially when they get complex.

Comment: @Error_2646, yep, agree, when it gets complex `case` is much better. But for simple things like this, especially when you have a lot of columns doing the same thing, the more concise option is appealing.

Comment: @PaulW, decode() also is specific to database. It would make code unportable. Not sure if it is ever worth it (not so readable as well).

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I understand, but 99% of systems will never get ported to a different RDBMS. The cost of porting is just too high in most cases, so it rarely happens. When coding in Oracle, it's overly restrictive to limit oneself to only things that are elusively pan-RDBMS. That would mean never using PL/SQL and dozens of other valuable features.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PIVOT ...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl_1 (ID, DATA) AS
        (   Select 1, 'bla' From Dual Union All 
            Select 2, 'blubb' From Dual
        ),
    tbl_2 (ID, KEY, VALUE) AS
        (   Select 1, 'apple', 5 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'orange', 3 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'pear', 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'apple', 4 From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n   S Q L :
Select  *
From    (   Select t1.ID, t1.DATA, t2.KEY, t2.VALUE
            From tbl_1 t1
            Left Join tbl_2 t2 ON(t2.ID = t1.ID)
        )
    PIVOT (Sum(VALUE) For Key IN('apple' "APPLE", 'orange' "ORANGE", 'pear' "PEAR"))
Order By ID
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID DATA       APPLE     ORANGE       PEAR
---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 bla            5          3          0
         2 blubb          4                         */
```